# Using the current file name (%) in command line mode when the file name contains spaces (or other special characters)

Tags: command-line

I cannot figure out the general rules for using `%` to substitute the current file name/path into a command line mode command.

Here are examples.

1. I create a file `te st.txt`, open it in vim and try to save a copy named `te st.txt.backup` with `:w %.backup`.
   This works as expected.
2. From the same file, I try to print it to a PostScript file with `:ha > %.ps`.
   This time, instead of `te st.txt.ps`, I get a PostScript file `te\ st.txt.ps`.
3. If I do `:exe "ha > " . expand("%") . ".ps"`, I get `te st.txt.ps`.

I do not follow the rules for using `%` in command line.
Are they documented somewhere?

Comment: I think the problem is related to the `:hardcopy` command, as I can't see this behaviour with other commands. Perhaps it is a bug? If you use `%` after a `:!` command, you should note that the `:S` modifier can be useful to automatically escape e.g. spaces in paths. E.g. `:!sort -u %:S`.

Comment: I created an [issue report](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1682) about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug, it must be fixed with [patch 8.0.0615](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/bf15b8d78b22661db8b19d662b62bb9a061cdd37).